# 153 seconds for a MySQL query, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with the following tables

```
german_akkusativ_plural [ akkusativ_plural, word_id ]
german_akkusativ_singular [ akkusativ_singular, word_id ]
german_dativ_plural [ dativ_plural, word_id ]
german_dativ_singular [ dativ_singular, word_id ]
german_gender [ gender, word_id ]
german_genitiv_plural [ genitiv_plural, word_id ]
german_genitiv_singular [ genitiv_singular, word_id ]
german_nominativ_plural [ nominativ_plural, word_id ]
german_nominativ_singular [ nominativ_singular, word_id ]
german_word [ id, word, blacklisted ]
```

and the following query which should find the corresponding gender of a word (the word can be in either one of the cases)

```
SELECT gg.gender
    FROM german_word gw
        INNER JOIN 
            german_nominativ_singular gns
            ON gw.id = gns.word_id
        INNER JOIN 
            german_nominativ_plural gnp
            ON gw.id = gnp.word_id
        INNER JOIN 
            german_akkusativ_singular gas
            ON gw.id = gas.word_id
        INNER JOIN 
            german_akkusativ_plural gap
            ON gw.id = gap.word_id
        INNER JOIN 
            german_dativ_singular gds
            ON gw.id = gds.word_id
        INNER JOIN 
            german_dativ_plural gdp
            ON gw.id = gdp.word_id
        INNER JOIN 
            german_genitiv_singular ggs
            ON gw.id = ggs.word_id
        INNER JOIN 
            german_genitiv_plural ggp
            ON gw.id = ggp.word_id
        INNER JOIN 
            german_gender gg
            ON gw.id = gg.word_id
    WHERE 
        gns.nominativ_singular = 'Auto' OR
        gnp.nominativ_plural = 'Auto' OR
        gas.akkusativ_singular = 'Auto' OR
        gap.akkusativ_plural = 'Auto' OR
        gds.dativ_singular = 'Auto' OR
        gdp.dativ_plural = 'Auto' OR
        ggs.genitiv_singular = 'Auto' OR
        ggp.genitiv_plural = 'Auto'
```

the problem is that when I run the query in phpMyAdmin it takes ~150 seconds to run. Why is that? I have indexes on all the fields except for 'blacklisted'.

Is this the correct approach or am I completely off track?

I would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks.

EDIT:

this is the output of EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys               key     key_len ref                         rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      gg      ALL     word_id                     NULL    NULL    NULL                        41522   
1   SIMPLE      gdp     ref     dativ_plural,word_id        word_id 5       usr_web410_3.gg.word_id     1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      ggp     ref     genitiv_plural,word_id      word_id 5       usr_web410_3.gg.word_id     1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      gap     ref     akkusativ_plural,word_id    word_id 5       usr_web410_3.gg.word_id     1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      gnp     ref     nominativ_plural,word_id    word_id 5       usr_web410_3.ggp.word_id    1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      gas     ref     akkusativ_singular,word_id  word_id 5       usr_web410_3.gg.word_id     1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      gns     ref     nominativ_singular,word_id  word_id 5       usr_web410_3.gg.word_id     1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      gds     ref     dativ_singular,word_id      word_id 5       usr_web410_3.gns.word_id    1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      ggs     ref     genitiv_singular,word_id    word_id 5       usr_web410_3.gg.word_id     1       Using where
1   SIMPLE      gw      eq_ref  PRIMARY                     PRIMARY 4       usr_web410_3.gg.word_id     1       Using index
```

Comment: Like with all other "slow query" questions, please show us the output of `EXPLAIN <your query>`. Index should be placed on all fields used in `JOIN`. I notice you have many `OR`s, I think this slows down. Maybe you can tighten this?

Comment: 1.see indexes in mysql 2. whats the point using lot of `inner joins` 3.when you talk about the execution time mention all stuff to help you optimize it(like `table structure`)

Comment: @DanFromGermany I have edited the questions to include the results of EXPLAIN

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi all fields are VARCHAR(255) except for word_id and id that are INT, the collation is utf8_general_ci, the storage engine is MyISAM and all tables have around 50k lines, I'm not sure if this is helpful or otherwise could you please be specific about the infos that you would like to have?

Comment: @DanFromGermany also word_id have indexes in all tables, I just realised that I wrote the contrary in the question

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi how would you look for the same result avoiding the inner joins? I am using php, I could also look for the word in the tables with single mysql queries, save the word_id if found and then look for the gender in yet another query, but I thought this would be slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching every row in each table, then you check if any table matches `'Auto'`. This is slow. These `OR`s are bad for performance so you must ditch them.

There are quite a few ways to rewrite your query, I'll only suggest one.
First of all, I see no reason for using the `german_word` table. It doesn't exist in any where or select clause, so we can just use the `german_gender` table. Remember that bigger SQL queries do not necessarily mean worse performance.

Try this one. It should bring the same results much faster. I assume that all text columns like `nominativ_singular` are indexed.

```
SELECT gg.gender as gender
FROM german_gender gg
    INNER JOIN german_nominativ_singular gns
    ON gg.word_id = gns.word_id AND gns.nominativ_singular = 'Auto'
UNION  
SELECT gg.gender as gender
FROM german_gender gg
    INNER JOIN german_nominativ_plural gnp
    ON gg.word_id = gnp.word_id AND gnp.nominativ_plural = 'Auto' 
UNION  
SELECT gg.gender as gender
FROM german_gender gg
    INNER JOIN german_akkusativ_singular gas
    ON gg.word_id = gas.word_id AND gas.akkusativ_singular = 'Auto' 
UNION  
SELECT gg.gender as gender
FROM german_gender gg
    INNER JOIN german_akkusativ_plural gap
    ON gg.word_id = gap.word_id AND gap.akkusativ_plural = 'Auto' 
UNION  
SELECT gg.gender as gender
FROM german_gender gg
    INNER JOIN german_dativ_singular gds
    ON gg.word_id = gds.word_id AND gds.dativ_singular = 'Auto' 
UNION  
SELECT gg.gender as gender
FROM german_gender gg
    INNER JOIN german_dativ_plural gdp
    ON gg.word_id = gdp.word_id AND gdp.dativ_plural = 'Auto' 
UNION  
SELECT gg.gender as gender
FROM german_gender gg
    INNER JOIN german_genitiv_singular ggs
    ON gg.word_id = ggs.word_id AND ggs.genitiv_singular = 'Auto' 
UNION  
SELECT gg.gender as gender
FROM german_gender gg
    INNER JOIN german_genitiv_plural ggp
    ON gg.word_id = ggp.word_id AND ggp.genitiv_plural = 'Auto'
```

Comment: Thank you this took just about 0.05 seconds!!